# On delete cascade weird behaviour

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I tried this in visual editor in Azure SQL, and SQL is not really my strongest skill.

Simple db with 2 tables.

```
Table Person with just id.
Table Hating with id, hater, target.
```

Both `Hating.hater` and `Hating.target` are required, both are foreign keys to `Person.id`
and both have ON DELETE CASCADE.

So essentially many-to-many relation between persons, with intention to delete the relation if originator or target is deleted.

However this will not work if both foreign keys are on cascade. Works fine if just other is, but not if both are.

Is this some restriction in SQL and is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 cascading keys in the same table. But, you can have a trigger do the work for you.  So instead of having two cascading keys, add a trigger to the person table (not tested but here is the idea):

```
    CREATE TRIGGER T_PERSON_CASCADE ON Person FOR DELETE AS

    DELETE FROM Hating WHERE hater IN (SELECT id FROM deleted) OR target IN (SELECT id FROM deleted)

    END
```

Comment: All right thanks. Was hoping I could handle this with just cascades, but apparently not.